# Change reception in postfix queue

Tags: postfix, email-server, queue

After running `postqueue -p` i sometimes finds misspelled email-adresses,
is there a way to change the reception adress (envelop to adress) of the messages,
so it can be delivered.

exemple:

```
postqueue -p
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
A78C42189B1     2523 Thu Jul 25 14:53:57  xxxx@xxxx.se
                (connect to tellia.com[141.8.224.25]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         yyyyy@tellia.com
-- 2 Kbytes in 1 Request.
```

I want to pick upp `A78C42189B1`, and change the adress `yyyyy@tellia.com` to `yyyyy@telia.com`

Comment: Looking for something like this too. I often see common misspelled stuff like "homail.com" or "hotmai.com".

Comment: if you always want to rewrite a domain, you can use recipient_canonical_maps, i use it whit mysql-query SELECT CONCAT('%u', '@', real_domain) FROM domains WHERE domain = '%d'

Answer (score 3):

So far i found out i can:

1. using `postcat -q A78C42189B1` i can get a copy of the queued item
2. clean the message from meta data, the postcat messages may look like:

   ```
   *** ENVELOPE RECORDS deferred/A/A78C42189B1 ***
   message_size:            2523             248               2               0            2523
   message_arrival_time: Thu Jul 25 14:53:57 2013
   create_time: Thu Jul 25 14:53:57 2013
   named_attribute: rewrite_context=local
   sender_fullname: nobody
   sender: FROM:xxxx@xxxx.se
   original_recipient: yyyyy@tellia.com
   recipient: yyyyy@tellia.com
   *** MESSAGE CONTENTS deferred/A/A78C42189B1 ***

   mail headers...

   mail body...

   *** HEADER EXTRACTED deferred/A/A78C42189B1 ***
   named_attribute: notify_flags=1
   original_recipient: backup@xxxx.se
   done_recipient: backup@xxxx.se
   *** MESSAGE FILE END deferred/A/A78C42189B1 ***
   ```

   Clean out the postfix header and footer, so only mail headers and mail body is left in the file, using a text editor, or sed.
3. use sendmail to send the mail to the new reciption

   ```
   sendmail yyyyy@telia.com < edited_mail_file
   ```
4. remove the original mail from the queue `postsuper -d mailID`

if someone with sed-skills, can cut out the mail header and body, the 3 first steps should be able to pipe togheter

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your described method is working with mail stuck in the mailqueue.

Though not really an answer to your specific issue, I'd like to share what I did to (re)solve some common misspelled domain-names in the future, using your hint:

In postfix/main.cf:

```
recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/maps/recipient_canonical
```

File /etc/postfix/maps/recipient_canonical:

```
/^(.*@)htomail.com$/ ${1}hotmail.com
/^(.*@)homail.com$/ ${1}hotmail.com
/^(.*@)hotmai.com$/ ${1}hotmail.com
/^(.*@)hotmai.co$/ ${1}hotmail.com
/^(.*@)hotma.com$/ ${1}hotmail.com
/^(.*@)gmial.com$/ ${1}gmail.com
/^(.*@)gmail.co$/ ${1}gmail.com
/^(.*@)gmail.nl$/ ${1}gmail.com
```