# Change recipient of all mail in Postfix queue

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

After running `postqueue -p` I noticed a lot of email that is stuck in queue to a entity that recently changed there domain.

Is there a way to change **all** the recipients of the mail stuck in queue addressed to *@entity.be to Banana@foo.com

So I can easily check which mails are important and need to be resent and which emails can be deleted.

I know I can manualy do all mails one by one with the [solution proposed here](https://serverfault.com/questions/527244/change-reception-in-postfix-queue) but is are simply to many to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to notice is that requeued messages are subject to address rewriting. So the simplest thing is to release and reque those e-mails and have the proper address rewriting enabled in postfix.

Like this:

```
recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical.pcre
```

With this content:

```
/^(.*@)entity.be$/ Banana@foo.com
```

Then release and requeue with

```
postsuper -HALL
postsuper -rALL
```